# TSQL: Getting error Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements

Tags: sql-server

I have a following error handling code:

```
Create PROC myProc(--Parameters--) 
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON

BEGIN TRAN
--My Code, combination of insertion and deletion

IF @@Error<>0
Goto ErrorSection

COMMIT TRAN
Return 0

ErrorSection:
    ROLLBACK TRAN
    raiserror(@error, 1, 2) with seterror
    return -1
END
```

Whenever my condition to check @@Error<>0 passes, my control executes ErrorSection code and through error,
"Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 1, current count = 0."

I am confused here that when control reaches ErrorSection, i should be having one active transaction which gets rollbacked immediately. So why i am getting this error.

I have also read some answers and used "SET XACT_ABORT ON" property which saves me from this error. Also i should use TRY-CATCH block as well. Since Rollback also reduces the transaction count to zero, so why i am getting this error when my rollback statement executes successfully.

I have also noticed that this error is generated just above Return -1 statement and then returns -1.

Kindly suggest why i am facing this error when rollback runs successfully and how "SET XACT_ABORT ON" saves me from the same.

Comment: Also when i am using "SET XACT_ABORT ON" in my code, i am not getting this error but the Return -1 statement is not getting executed and SP returns nothing in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using GOTO statements for errorhandling. Instead, use TRY...CATCH to handle errors and rollback transactions:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

BEGIN TRY
    -- Code that might generate an error here
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;

    -- Your custom code for error handling here
END CATCH;

IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    COMMIT TRANSACTION;

    -- Clean-up code here
GO
```

Comment: Thanks Dan for your suggestion, actually I am willing just to understand that why i am getting error even when i am successfully running ROLLBACK command.